# Any idea how can I optimize morlet wavelet parameters by Heisenberg uncertainty principal and Shannon entropy?

Tags: wavelet, optimization

Based on a paper in [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X05003913), they have proposed a method to optimize morlet function parameter. I have tried to implement their technique, but I can't get rational results. any idea?
In here you can see what they have done briefly:
Imagine you have a signal with following frequency and damping pairs :
$(f_i ,\zeta_i), (f_{i+1},\zeta_{i+1})$ and $f_i,f_{i+1} $ are two closely spaced frequency i.e. $1.01Hz,1,09 Hz$
now we define $f_{i,i+1}=\frac{f_i+f_{i+1}}{2}$ and $\Delta f_{i,i+1}=f_{i+1}-f_i$
based on Heisenberg uncertainty principle the $f_c\sqrt{f_b}$ must be in range of :
$2\alpha\frac{f_{i,i+1}}{2\pi\Delta f_{i,i+1}}\leqslant f_c\sqrt{f_b}\leqslant \frac{2\gamma}{\beta}Tf_i;[1_a] $
for another reason $f_c \geq  \frac{5}{2\pi};[1_b]$
which demonstrates that $f_c\sqrt{f_b}$should be chosen within an interval so that a compromise could
be made between frequency and time resolutions, Another consideration is that because $f_c\sqrt{f_b}$ is within an interval, there exist numerous pairs of $f_b$and $f_c$. Practically, it is necessary to introduce some other criteria to select optimum values of $f_b$ and $f_c$, the minimum Shannon entropy is used for criteria :
$E=-\sum_{i=1}^{M}d_i log(d_i)[2]$,  where $d_i$ is:   $d_i=\frac{|W(a_i,t)|}{\sum_{j=1}^{M}W(a_j,t)}$ $,M$ is number of scales
so we must minimize $E$ from equation[2] in range of [$1_a,1_b$].
I have used `fmincon` matlab function   to solve this non linear unequality constrain in matlab
[1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X05003913)

Comment: I can't read the paper as it is paywalled, so can't help you. Not that I would likely be able to understand your question even if I could.

Comment: Ah wait maybe I would be able to understand it after all I was just a bit tired when I read the question. But I'm a poor hobby researcher so sadly I can't afford to pay by the copy.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for your attention. I solved the paper 2 years ago and published the paper on that. :)

Comment: Ah great, is it possible to read it somewhere? I think I maybe would find it interesting.

Comment: Sure please write down your email. @mathreadler